# GPC - Cloud Build: Error pushing an docker image - An image does not exist locally with the tag

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I got my project in gitlab and push it to Google Cloud Plattform, to build, push and deploy.
The first step building it, works fine and finished with:

> Built and pushed image as gcr.io/my-project/backend

But always the second step is failing with this:

> The push refers to repository [gcr.io/my-project/backend]
> An image does not exist locally with the tag: gcr.io/my-project/backend

My cloudbuild.yaml

```
 # build the container image
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn:3.5.0-jdk-8'
    args: ['clean', 'install', 'jib:build', '-Dimage=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/backend']
    # push the container image
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/backend:latest']
```

Comment: I think you can directly build and push your image with JIB, no need to use docker push (the target of JIB is to create and push container without having Docker installed!!)

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to tag the image with the `args`:

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  id: 'backend'
  args: [
    'build',
    '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/backend:${SHORT_SHA}',
    '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/backend:latest',
    ...
  ]
```

An `images` block also seems to be missing:

```
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/backend:${SHORT_SHA}'
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/backend:latest'
```

With image-tagging set up, that error message should disappear.

And in order to configure Docker for the Google Container Registry:

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

See [Storing images in Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containers#store-images) for reference.

Comment: Thanks, but thats all just for building with the cloud-builders/docker not with jib right?

Comment: I've just checked and think that you'd need an extra `build` step, in between `jib:build` and  `push`, then the documentation suddenly makes sense. `mvn` may build the application, but not the container.

Comment: You are sure? 
jib:build builds an image and I can see it already in the container registry.
And its also working from locally with:
 mvn compile com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:2.8.0:build \
        -Dimage=gcr.io/PROJECT/IMAGE

https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/jib?hl=eng